# Check date interval before submitting

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have two `DatePickers`, which allows the user to define an interval between two dates.  I want to know how to check that the `date-interval` is maximum 30 days between these. If not, an alert mentioning this should pop up and the request is not sent.

I have a `div`:

```
<div id="excelExportDiv" class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt date_glyphicon top-4" data-url="@Url.Action("CreateExcelFile","Customer", new {id = Model.Konstants.First().STATION, xx="4", start = "", end = "", includeInactiveInExport = "" })"></div>
```

An associated [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)that updates the parameters sent.

```
$(function excelFunction() {
  $('#excelExportDiv').click(function() {
    var start = $('#startDateTextBox').val();
    var end = $('#endDateTextBox').val();
    var checkedValue = "off";
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('messageCheckbox');
    for (var i = 0; inputElements[i]; ++i) {
      if (inputElements[i].checked) {
        checkedValue = "on";
        break;
      }
    }
    var url = $(this).data("url") + "&start=" + start + "&end=" + end + "&includeInactiveInExport=" + checkedValue;
    window.location.href = url;
  });
});
```

The logic for checking the `date-interval` is already written, so basically I have an `if` statement as follows:

```
if (diffDays > 30) {
  alert("Maximum range is 30 days!");
  return false;
} else {
  //submit the action...
}
```

I want the form to be sent if the `if` statement is true. Any ideas?

Comment: Would be simpler if you  get each date object from the api of the datepicker plugin you are using. From there it is easy to research how to get the difference between 2 dates

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to parse these dates into [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. For example: `new Date(end)` and `new Date(start)`.
2. Subtract its values. The result is a difference in milliseconds:

   **`(new Date(end) - new Date(start))`**
3. Finally, convert it to a day with: `(valueInMilliseconds)/1000/60/60/24`. For example:

   **`diffDays = (new Date(end) - new Date(start)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;`**

Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#startDateTextBox, #endDateTextBox").datepicker();

  $("#excelExportDiv").on("click", function() {
    var start = $("#startDateTextBox").val(),
      end = $("#endDateTextBox").val(),
      diffDays;

    diffDays = (new Date(end) - new Date(start)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

    console.log(diffDays);

    if (diffDays > 30) {
      alert("Maximum range is 30 days!");
      return false;
    } else {
      //submit the action...
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 2px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

#excelExportDiv {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: solid 1px #7e8da2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Start date</label>
  <input type="text" id="startDateTextBox">
</div>
<div>
  <label>End date</label>
  <input type="text" id="endDateTextBox">
</div>


<div id="excelExportDiv" class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt date_glyphicon top-4">Export</div>
```

Hope this helps.